# PostgreSQL: Can't reference column from nested select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query that includes a nested `SELECT`. However, Postgres throws this error when I try to run my code: `ERROR: column bo_wins.opportunity_id does not exist`. Here is the query:

```
SELECT b.owner_id AS "Owner ID",
       COUNT(DISTINCT bo.id) AS "Number of Opportunities",
       COALESCE(bo_wins.count, 0) AS "Number of Wins"
FROM bookings b
INNER JOIN booking_opportunities bo ON bo.id = b.opportunity_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT b.owner_id AS "Owner ID", COUNT(DISTINCT bo.id) AS "count"
     FROM bookings b 
     INNER JOIN booking_opportunities bo ON bo.id = b.opportunity_id 
     WHERE bo.state IN ('won') AND TO_CHAR(bo.created_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2016-06' 
     GROUP BY b.owner_id
     ) AS bo_wins ON bo_wins.opportunity_id = b.opportunity_id
WHERE TO_CHAR(bo.created_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2016-06'
GROUP BY bo_wins.count, b.owner_id;
```

Hope somebody is able to help me out. The reason I need to do a subquery is because of how our database is structured (I know! Not very efficient, huh?)

EDIT: I aliased my `COUNT` in the subquery. It still throws me the same error.

Comment: you are not selecting `opportunity_id` the column at all in the derived table aliased as `bo_wins`.

Comment: How am I supposed to that when I am doing a `COUNT`?

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers - If you are trying to aggregate wins at the owner grain, why then are you joining on `opportunity_id`?

Comment: This was the solution. This is probably the third time I use a nested select, hence me making a rookie mistake like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I think what you are trying to do is better represented this way:

```
SELECT
    b.owner_id AS owner_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT bo.id) AS opportunities,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bo.state = 'won' THEN bo.id END) AS wins
FROM
    bookings b 
INNER JOIN
    booking_opportunities bo
    ON (bo.id = b.opportunity_id)
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(bo.created_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2016-06' 
GROUP BY
    b.owner_id;
```

This gives you the number of opportunities and number of wins for each `owner_id`.

---

**Initial Answer**

You need to give your calculation an alias AND you need to include `opportunity_id` in that same select statement.

`COUNT(DISTINCT bo.id) AS "count"`

Also, in your `GROUP BY` you need to change `bo.wins.count` to `bo_wins.count`

Comment: How am I supposed to do include `opportunity_id` when I am doing a COUNT?

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers - Aren't you just trying to get the number of opportunities and wins for each `owner_id`? If so, my updated answer provides you with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yo should add an alias to COUNT(DISTINCT bo.id)